# gcloud error when deploying to google app engine flexible environment

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, app-engine-flexible, app.yaml

Recently I have needed to add web sockets to my backend application currently hosted on Google App  Engine (GAE) standard environment. Because web sockets are a feature only available in GAE's flexible environment, I have been attempting a redeployment but with little success.

To make the change to a flexible environment I have updated the app.yaml file from

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard
```

to

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

While previously working in the standard environment, now with `env: flex` when I run the command `gcloud app deploy --app-yaml=app-staging.yaml --verbosity=debug` I get the following stack trace:

```
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
DEBUG: Using bucket [gs://staging.finnsalud.appspot.com].
DEBUG: Service [appengineflex.googleapis.com] is already enabled for project [finnsalud]
Beginning deployment of service [finnsalud-staging]...
INFO: Using ignore file at [~/checkouts/twilio/backend/.gcloudignore].
DEBUG: not expecting type '<class 'NoneType'>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 982, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 115, in Run
    return deploy_util.RunDeploy(
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 669, in RunDeploy
    deployer.Deploy(
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 428, in Deploy
    source_files = source_files_util.GetSourceFiles(
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/source_files_util.py", line 184, in GetSourceFiles
    return list(it)
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/gcloudignore.py", line 233, in GetIncludedFiles
    six.ensure_str(upload_directory), followlinks=True):
  File "//google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/six/__init__.py", line 884, in ensure_str
    raise TypeError("not expecting type '%s'" % type(s))
TypeError: not expecting type '<class 'NoneType'>'
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): not expecting type '<class 'NoneType'>'
```

In this stack trace, it mentions an error in `google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/gcloudignore.py` so I had also reviewed my .gcloudignore file but was unable to find anything out of place:

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
node_modules/
```

In an attempt to work around this bug I tried removing my .gcloudignore file which resulted in a different error, but still failed nevertheless:

```
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
DEBUG: Using bucket [gs://staging.finnsalud.appspot.com].
DEBUG: Service [appengineflex.googleapis.com] is already enabled for project [finnsalud]
Beginning deployment of service [finnsalud-staging]...
DEBUG: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 982, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 115, in Run
    return deploy_util.RunDeploy(
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 669, in RunDeploy
    deployer.Deploy(
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 428, in Deploy
    source_files = source_files_util.GetSourceFiles(
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/source_files_util.py", line 184, in GetSourceFiles
    return list(it)
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/util.py", line 165, in FileIterator
    entries = set(os.listdir(os.path.join(base, current_dir)))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Thinking maybe this was an error relating to the version of my CLI I have also run the following commands to try and update:

```
gcloud app update
gcloud components update
```

Unfortunately, this had no change on the output.

I have noticed that when I run this command with the app.yaml `env` value set to `flexible`, there are no updates to the logging section on google cloud and no changes to the files uploaded to the project's storage bucket. To me, this indicates that the crash is occurring in the CLI before any communication to the google cloud services is made. If this is correct, then it seems unlikely that the cause of the error would be related to a bad configuration on google cloud and must be related to something (software or configuration) on my local machine.

I have also tried using the 'Hello World' app.yaml configuration on the flexible environments '[Getting Started](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)' page to rule out a configuration error my own application's `app.yaml` but this also had no change on the output.

Finally, if at any point I change `env: flex` back to `env: standard` then the issue does disappear. Unfortunately, as stated above, this won't work for deploying my web sockets feature.

This has gotten me thinking that possibly the error is due to a bug with the gcloud cli application. However, if this were the case, I would have expected to see many more bug reports for this issue by others whom are also using the GAE's flexible environment.

Regardless, given this stack trace points to code within the gcloud cli, I have opened a bug ticket with google which can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176839574

I have also seen this similar SO post, but it is not the exact error I am experiencing and remains unresolved: [gcloud app deploy fails with flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427909/gcloud-app-deploy-fails-with-flexible-environment)

If anyone has any ideas on other steps to try or methods to overcome this issue, I would be immensely grateful if you drop a note on this post. Thanks!

Comment: hi, just as @Marian i tried to replicate the issue, and got no error  when using `runtime: nodejs` `env: flex`  this make me think is something particular to your usecase, could you share the code of the app having this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, this issue does seem to be related to a bug in the gcloud cli. However, there does seem to be a workaround.

When a `--appyaml` flag is specified for a deployment to the flex environment, then the CLI crashes with the messages outlines in my question above. However, if you copy your .yaml file renaming to `app.yaml` (the default) and delete this `--appyaml` flag when deploying then the build will proceed without errors.

If you have also experienced this error, please follow the google [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176839574)  as I am working with the google engineers to be sure they reproduce and eventually fix this bug.

Comment: All they have to do is add their yaml file to s subdirectory and --appyaml=/dir/app.yaml and they can reproduce the error, meanwhile its kind of frustrating when you have multiple services to have to keep swapping out yaml files means deployment cant be easily automated

Answer (score 0):

I deployed a nodejs application using the [Quickstart for Node.js in the standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart#local-machine)

Then I changed the app.yaml file from :

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

to

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

Everything worked as expected.

It might be related to your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please correct me if I have missed something: Isn't this the same change I made to the app.yaml indicated in the first two code blocks of my questions? Asking for clarification in case I have overlooked some nuance.

Comment: Yes, it is the same change. I wanted to test if it is a bug with the gcloud cli application and I get the same results as you. I could not replicate your issue.

Comment: When you say that you get the same result as I, do you mean that you are also seeing the error message? I wasn't certain due to the following statement indicating that you could not replicate the issue. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I have tried to deploy the project from a separate computer to see if the issue was isolated to a single machine. However, I am getting the same error messages on both computers that I own.

Comment: I wanted to reproduce your issue but everything worked as expected. Are you facing the same issue if you deploy only the Quickstart?.

Answer (score 0):

Broken app.yaml

```
runtime:nodejs14
```

Fixed app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14
```

I am dead serious. And :

```
glcoud info --run-diagnostics
```

was ZERO HELP.

Once I did this the **"ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): expected string or bytes-like object"** went away.

I guess "colon + space" is part of the spec:
[Why does the YAML spec mandate a space after the colon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124227/why-does-the-yaml-spec-mandate-a-space-after-the-colon)